# Delete reasons in the Low Quality Posts review queue are alternating

Tags: bug, review, low-quality

While reviewing posts in the Low Quality Posts queue I noticed that the available delete reasons were alternating between different options.

Every second time the first option says:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

And the other half of the times the first option says:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

What is the reason for this alternation? And can it be fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the reputation level of the person whose answer you're reviewing. If they have too low a reputation to be able to post comments, the first option will be used. If they have enough reputation, the second will be used.

Comment: You are right. I hadn't realized that one of the users had enough reputation to comment and that that actually triggers a change in the wording. It all makes sense now. Thank you.